# Restore of Replicated Database fails with “Cannot drop the table <table name> because it is being used for replication.”

Tags: transactional-replication

published database restoration failed once you setup transactional Replication using system Store procedures. Few work around to this problem is restore with KEEP_replication option and than drop the publication and subscription.

Is there anything we can do while setting up the Transactional replication using System SP that can avoid this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below query to avoid replication related SP in Transactional Replication.

SELECT name 'ROUTINE_NAME','T' 'ROUTINE_TYPE'
            FROM sys.tables 
            WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID,'TableHasPrimaryKey') = 1 AND name not like 'MSpeer%'